# Clarification of problem instruction on ring theory problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to solve Lang's chapter II problem 10. The first statement of the problem is confusing me. It says:

"Let P be the set of positive integers and R the set of functions defined on P with values in  commutative ring K."

Does this mean R = K[x], where x could only be positive integers? Or what exactly does "set of functions defined on P" mean? Also, what does "with values in a commutative ring K" mean?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$R$ is just the set of all functions $f:P\to K$.  "Functions defined on $P$" means the domain of the functions is $P$, and "with values in $K$" means the codomain of the functions is $K$.